# How to draw caret in the scroll view on iOS using system API?

Tags: ios, caret

I am working on an edit app, the view inherits from scroll view, and I draw most things manually. I need an insertion indicator, which may refer to caret(as I know windows use this term) or cursor(not the mouse cursor). I am not sure what term apple use.

I googled before and I know I can draw it as a line manually, or create a clear background text view over it, but I don't like these ways. I hope there are system APIs to do this, which is more native. Any one can figure out?

Comment: It's an old question, but I'd with adding a `UITextView` with "clear background", and then draw the text one finished or take a screenshot of the whole content.